# criar um ficheiro bat

Tags: bat

Preciso criar um ficheiro `bat` para alterar o ip da placa de rede e depois abrir o `cmd` com umas linhas de comando.
Neste caso seria para ficar algo assim:

> - Alterar o ip
> - Abrir o `cmd`
> - Colocar linhas de comando necessárias.

Ate abrir o `cmd` eu já consegui mas não consigo colocar a escrever la depois, alguem pode ajudar.

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

start /max "cmd.exe"

ssh xxxxxx@192.168.1.1

12345678
```

Answer (score 3):

---

> > • Se entendi a pergunta, posso sugerir que use um bat para criar um segundo bat e chamar esse segundo usando o **`start /max`** já finalizando o primeiro bat...

---

```bat
@echo off  && >nul chcp 1252 & type nul >"%temp%\bat_to_bat.bat"
:: alterando o IP:

rem :: Configurando IP: 192.168.1.100 ^| Mascara: 255.255.255.0 ^| Gateway: 192.168.1.1
netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
rem :: Configurando DNS Primario: 1.1.1.1
netsh interface ip add dns "Ethernet" 1.1.1.1
rem :: DNS Secundario: 1.0.0.1
netsh interface ip add dns "Ethernet" 1.0.0.1 index=2

>"%temp%\bat_to_bat.bat"^
   (
    echo/    @echo off & color 0a
    echo/    ssh [usuário]@192.168.1.1
    echo/    [Senha]
   ) && start /max cmd.exe /k call "%temp%\bat_to_bat.bat" <nul & exit /b
```

---

> > Ou com todas as **ações em um só bat** chamando o cmd e executando os comandos...4

---

```bat
@echo off && >nul chcp 1252 & type nul >"%temp%\bat_to_bat.bat"

>"%temp%\bat_to_bat.bat"^
    ( 
     echo/    @echo off & color 0a
     echo/    rem :: Configurando IP: 192.168.1.100 ^| Mascara: 255.255.255.0 ^| Gateway: 192.168.1.1
     echo/    netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
     echo/    rem :: Configurando DNS Primario: 1.1.1.1
     echo/    netsh interface ip add dns "Ethernet" 1.1.1.1
     echo/    rem :: DNS Secundario: 1.0.0.1
     echo/    netsh interface ip add dns "Ethernet" 1.0.0.1 index=2
     echo/    ssh [usuário]@192.168.1.1
     echo/    [senha]
     echo/
    ) && start /max cmd.exe /k call "%temp%\bat_to_bat.bat" <nul & exit /b
```

<kbd>**`• Obs.:`**</kbd>

> 1. *Edite/ajuste a linha com os ips* ***`netsh interface ip...`***
> 2. *O bat precisa ser executado como* ***Administrador***

Comment: gostei da técnica de agrupar os comandos com "(" e ")" para criar um outro arquivo...normalmente eu coloco ">" e depois ">>" em cada linha...essa técnica eu conheço do bash (onde "(" e ")" delimitam um sub-shell) mas nunca pensei em usar no cmd

Answer (score 0):

so precisa abri o cmd com o comando /C, 
tudo que vai depois do /c é copiado para console.

exemplo:

```
start cmd /C ping 10.0.0.1 -t
```